# Where/How is the function representation as shown in IPython REPL generated?

Tags: python, function, ipython, repr

For example, in REPL:

```
In  [0]: def func(x=0, y=1):
    ...:     return x

In  [1]: func
Out [1]: <function __main__.func(x=0, y=1)>
```

But how do I print it or store in a variable?

```
In  [2]: print(func)
Out [2]: 
<function func at 0x000002182B32F5E0>

In  [3]: str(func)
Out [3]: <function func at 0x000002182B32F5E0>

In  [4]: repr(func)
Out [4]: <function func at 0x000002182B32F5E0>
```

One way would be to:

```
In  [5]: string = eval('func')

In  [6]: print(string)

Out [6]: 
<function __main__.func(x=0, y=1)>
```

But this does not look safe, and even if it is, I want to know what method of the function generates this. For example `str` invokes internal `__str__` or `repr` invokes internal `__repr__`. Or is it just `eval` formatting this?

As a workaround, I can do:

```
In  [7]: from inspect import signature

In  [8]: sign = str(signature(d)).strip('<Signature />')

In  [9]: string = f"<{func.__class__.__name__} {func.__module__}.{func.__name__}{sign}>"

In  [10]: print(string)
Out [10]:
<function __main__.func(x=0, y=1)>
```

This works, but it seems like I am doing work that's already been done, and I am reluctant to use `eval`. Is there any other way I can get this? It seems like I am missing something very simple.

**NOTE**:
Version:
IPython 3.8.5

[image]

Comment: That's the output of `repr()`

Comment: @tripleee Doesn't seem so, `repr(func)` gives me `<function func at 0x000002182B32F5E0>`

Comment: Which Python version is this? I can't reproduce you initial output with versions 3.6, 3.7 nor 3.8.

Comment: IPython, 3.8.5, I will update

Comment: IPython implements it's own pretty-printer.

Comment: `>>>` implies python repl, which makes your code misleading

Comment: Right, understood, that's what I was looking for.

Comment: @MadPhysicist True, did not assume it to be IPython specific, I was wrong to do so. Thank you.